# How do companies secure JavaScript client libraries?

Tags: javascript, web-services, rest

How do services which have JavaScript client libraries secure those libraries and the APIs they call? Specifically:

1. Ensure library is only loaded on valid sites.
2. Ensure a user doesn't just open up the console and start making calls.

Any other major considerations to be made?

Comment: That is a difficult question to accurately answer. The more critical inquiry is how does any user of the interwebs verify anything with certainty if you do not have control over or access to the data transmitted over the lines or frequencies - once send is pressed. If you cannot review 80TB a second in real time then you may miss something; if you can, you may be able to miss nothing.

Comment: 1) You really can't 2) You can't.....

Comment: *Never trust the client*

Answer (score 1):

> Ensure library is only loaded on valid sites.

You can't and you don't. Security in client-side JS is futile. If you're talking server-side JS, you're pretty much pwned if arbitrary code is able to execute server-side.

> Ensure a user doesn't just open up the console and start making calls.

Most services require some form of API key/token, a value that needs to go with your API requests so that the service can check its validity. This value is usually only obtainable by being a registered user of the service. That means an API key is tied to an account. If the service finds out that you're breaking ToS, they can simply block your API key or account altogether.

For public APIs, there's a combination of rate limiting, tracking and blocking (i.e. IP or a fingerprint of some sort), referrer checks (ensure something is only loaded by a certain page, not somewhere else), UA checks (ensure a browser is downloading, not a bot, app or something), and more. Individually, these checks are easily spoofed, but combined, can be a deterrent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since your js basically lives client side then the only thing you could really do there is make users authenticate before they can really get your libraries. Anything past that would really just be a tiny roadbump to anyone who really wants to manipulate your js.

Where you do have and can maintain control is securing your API calls. The most popular forms are with basic auth, OAuth, and IP whitelisting.